# How to show pre-filtered list on a search results area

Tags: mobile, android, ios, material-design

I am working an iOS app that manage employees requests,
I have a screen that shows requests, and a search field above it, I can search within my requests.
but, I can also send a push notification with a batch of requests, all from the same day and type.

Is there a method, preferably something that is recommended by apple or at least google, to communicate where the this list came from?

P.S.
We don't have information of the common that these requests have, such as their type or date, we can only tell the user that they all came from the same notification batch..

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "communicate where the this list came from"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, perhaps you can provide a better one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but it sounded to be like you are looking for a way to educate the users on what contents are within this list (e.g. different types of requests).

If that is the case, for iOS there are various list section header patterns that you can use to create labels for your list items if it makes sense to group them. [image]

Answer (score 0):

the question doesnt specify

- if user can see request from more than one batch
- if yes, is there a screen where he can select from which batch he wants to see the requests

Solution

- if the user only sees the request from one batch then it can be mentioned on the header like the first mockup
- Or else if user has access to requests from. multiple batches then we can do something like mockup 2
  here the only cons is if there are too many of them it will look bad

[image: Mockups]